# Postgresql/SQL insert into table based on multiple column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

My origin table looks like this

```
company_name | feature_name | feature_value
 abc         |   income     |  315
 abc         |   cash       |  213
 abc         |   val        |  9
 goo         |   income     |  123
 goo         |   cash       |  487
 goo         |   val        |  990
```

I want to insert into a new table so that the new table looks like this, and the new table won't contain column for cash.

```
company_name | income_name | income_value | val_name | val_value
 abc         |   income    |   315        |  val     |  9
 goo         |   income    |   123        |  val     |  990
```

I've checked a lot of posts but still don't know how to do that. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It's called a pivot query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pivot data without using any proprietary syntax you have a couple of options. Group/max on conditionals or left join multiple times:

```
SELECT
  company_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'income' THEN feature_value END as income,
  MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'val' THEN feature_value END as val,
  ...
FROM
  table
GROUP BY company name
```

To see how it works run it without the group by and max operations; you'll see how the case when spreads the single value column out into multiple columns, multiple rows per company. The group by and max collapse these multiple rows to a single row by removing all the nulls

If your table is just a snippet you can add more columns where the ... is by copying the pattern. Remember to remove the trailing comma from the select list items

The join way:

```
SELECT
  t.company_name,
  income.feature_value as income,
  val.feature_value as val,
  ...
FROM
  table t
  LEFT JOIN table income ON t.company_name = income.company_name and income.feature_name = 'income' 
  LEFT JOIN table val ON t.company_name = val.company_name and val.feature_name = 'val' 
  ...
```

This virtually splits the table into multiple tables each having the company name and just some of the rows, making a table per feature, then joins them all back together into one multi column result set

I've always preferred the group way but you'd have to trial which was more efficient for your situation and which is easier to maintain for your understanding

Inserting data from a select into another table is a very common operation so I've omitted that part for clarity- this is just to show you how to pivot the data. The insert will be one of:

```
INSERT INTO existingtable(company_name, income, val)
SELECT ...

CREATE newtable AS
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with conditional aggregation using `case when expression`

```
   select company_name, 
          max(case when feature_name='income' then feature_name end) as income_name,
          max(case when feature_name='income' then feature_name end) as income_value,
          max(case when feature_name='val' then feature_name end) as val_name,
          max(case when feature_name='val' then feature_name end) as val_value
    from tablename
    group by company_name
```